# ReportViewer10 export to excel 2007, copy and paste change colors

Tags: reportviewer

My problem:

I have created a report with Visual studio 2010(ReportViewer 10, client side report). Then copy and paste a table or some cells with background colors(such as blue) in my report to a new excel file(not another tab in the same excel file) . The blue color becomes red.

I think that the report is generated with Excel 2003, my guess. Is there a way to tell it to export the excel file with excel 2007?